# Can the Zariski topology range over infinite sets of polynomials?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

I need someone to sanity check my understanding: I believe when we define the closed sets of the Zariski topology as:

$$
C \in \mathbb R^n~\text{is closed} \iff \exists S, f_{s \in S}: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow  \mathbb R, ~ \left\{ x \in \mathbb R^n : \forall s \in S, f_s(x) = 0 \right\} = C
$$

and that the index  set $S$ *can be infinite*. Is this correct?

I believe that it needs to be infinite to prove that the intersection of two closed sets is closed:

$$
\begin{align*}
C &\equiv \{ x \in \mathbb R^n: \forall s \in S, f_s(x) = 0 \} \\
D &\equiv \{ x \in \mathbb R^n: \forall t \in T, g_t(x) = 0 \} \\
C \cap D &\equiv \{ x \in \mathbb R^n: \forall s \in S, f_s(x) = 0 \land \forall t \in T, g_t(x) = 0 \}
\end{align*}
$$

Our index set for $C \cap D $ is now ranging over $S \cup T$. To have *infinite* intersection, we might potentially need to allow an *infinite* number of polynomials.

Is there a **deeper** reason for allowing the closed sets to have potentially infinite sets of polynomials, than just "we need it to satisfy the axioms of a Topology"?

Comment: Not to directly answer your query about the Zariski topology, but note that we do not need an infinite number of closed sets in order to satisfy the requirement that an *infinite intersection* of closed sets is closed in a topology.  For example, the trivial topology on a (nonempty) set $S$ has exactly two closed sets (equiv. two open sets).

Comment: Yes, the index set is allowed to be infinite - and as you observe, this is necessary in order for the Zariski topology to actually be a topology. I'm not sure what you mean by "deeper reason," though - could you elaborate?

Comment: Is there some algebro-geometric reason where if we forego infinite sets, some extremely important theorem fails to hold? Or something that we hold intuitive fails to work out? The Zariski topology does not appear very natural to me, so perhaps fitting our definitions of affine sets to get the (very weak) topological structure might not be worth it?  What fails if we only call sets defined by zeros of a finite number of polynomials as algebraic?

Comment: Yes, the index set is allowed to be infinite.  That said -- as it turns out, for the specific case of the field being $\mathbb{R}$, every Zariski closed set is actually the zero set of a *single* polynomial function.  (For general fields, a finite number of polynomials is always sufficient.)

Comment: That's not to say that expressing an infinite intersection of closed sets with $S$ finite for each is necessarily trivial to express as a set with its $S$ finite.  (Though you do have the property that the Zariski topology is Noetherian: any decreasing sequence of closed sets stabilizes after some finite number, so any infinite intersection of closed sets is equal to the intersection of finitely many of them.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler so if I understand correctly, the Zariski topology does not need infinite intersection, even over arbitrary rings since the ideals are going to be Noetherian? Or is this only over fields?

Comment: I suppose it would work over Noetherian rings as well.  Though I don't know if I've ever seen the Zariski topology used over any rings other than fields.  (With the possible exceptions of zero sets of polynomials being a building block of the definition of a diophantine subset of $\mathbb{Z}^n$.)